# How to quit the application from the code

Tags: lua, coronasdk, quit

I am building a game using corona sdk. Inside the game, at the menu, I have an EXIT button. I want to know how I can quit the application and get to the mobile home screen or mobile menu? In other words, what should I write inside the `onExitButtonClicked(event)` method?

*The application/Game is not resume able.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ( but should not ) call `os.exit()` or on Android call `native.requestExit()`.

Normal apps do not quit, the user just switches app or kills the app.

You can find more documentation here: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/os/exit.html

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. It is better to code this way.
function quit()
 os.exit()
end   
timer.performWithDelay(1000,quit)

So, now it won't look like a crash.

Answer (score -1):

It worked. Thanks a lot. It is better to code this way.

```
function quit() 
 os.exit() 
end 
timer.performWithDelay(1000,quit)
```

So, now it won't look like a crash.